# Why am I getting date: illegal time format?

Tags: bash, macos, date, quoting

If I run this command on OSX bash terminal:

```
date -jf '%F %TZ' -v+$((10**9))S -u "2011-04-25 00:00:00Z"
```

I get exactly what I want: Thu Jan  1 01:46:40 UTC 2043

but when I run:

```
./gigasecond.sh '2011-04-25'
```

I get:

```
2011-04-25 00:00:00Z
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

All gigabit.sh contains is:

```
#!/bin/bash
size=${#1}
DATE_SET_TO_MIDNIGHT="${1%Z} 00:00:00Z"
echo $DATE_SET_TO_MIDNIGHT
PARSE_DATE_AND_FORMAT=$(date -jf '%F %TZ' -v+$((10**9))S -u "$DATE_SET_TO_MIDNIGHT")
echo $PARSE_DATE_AND_FORMAT
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote `$DATE_SET_TO_MIDNIGHT`, because it contains whitespace.

```
PARSE_DATE_AND_FORMAT=$(date '%F %TZ' -v+$((10**9))S -u "$DATE_SET_TO_MIDNIGHT")
```

Unless you have a very good reason *not* to, you should *always* quote parameter expansions.

Comment: I updated my code to include `-jf` in the script.  Does not work without it.